# What type of clouds are these?

Tags: atmosphere, clouds, identification-request

I would appreciate some help in identifying these clouds:

[image: http://i.imgur.com/rwhWWii.jpg]

This was taken on a commercial plane flying between Hong Kong and Japan on the 31st of March around 2pm.

I tried looking up cloud types but was not too sure. This sort of had two different looks - one being a flat kind of sea, and the other being the smaller, noisier clouds popping up from underneath.

Thanks very much.

Comment: Heh, interesting - people are used to identifying cloud types from below....

Comment: I suppose you were flying above the ocean when you took the photo?

Comment: Yes I believe we were still above ocean.

Comment: This is a bit out of my field, but can they not be two different types of clouds? So you have stratus (or whatever the flat ones are) with patches of cumulus (or whatever the puffy ones are). I am not too clear on how real clouds are classified, since I have only dealt with this in toy examples at school.

Answer (score 2):

Mostly stratocumulus with a scattering of emergent cumulus towers which have been lofted by strong internal convection cells.